# Stored Procedure update with parameter a column name from a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Consider this little script for an example

```
create table Customers
(CustomerId int not null
,StoreId int
,primary key(CustomerId)
)
go
create table Stores
(StoreId int
,StoreName varchar(50)
,primary key(StoreId)
)
go
alter table Customers
add foreign key (StoreId)
references Stores(StoreId)
go

insert into Stores
values   (1,'Biggest Store')
        ,(2,'Mediumest Store')
        ,(3,'Smaller Store')
        ,(4,'Smallest Store')
go
insert into Customers
values
         (1,1)
        ,(2,1)
        ,(3,2)
        ,(4,3)
        ,(5,4)
```

Let's say that I want to use a stored update called `spUpdateCustomerInformation`
that takes two parameters: one is the `CustomerId` and the other is the name of the store which the user wishes to update (StoreName from the Stores table).  So in the `Customers` table the record `(1,1)` means that customer 1 bought something from `Biggest Store`.  I would like to pass two parameters to the stored procedure like `spUpdateCustomerInformation 1,'Smallest Store'` and after the stored procedure is ran the record that was `(1,1)` is now
`(1,4)`.  My attempt

```
create proc spUpdateCustomerInformation
 @CustomerId int
,@StoreName varchar(50)
as begin
update c
set c.StoreId = s.StoreId
from customers as c
inner join Stores as s
on s.StoreId = c.StoreId
where c.CustomerID = @CustomerId
      and s.StoreName = @StoreName --failing here
end
```

returns 0 rows updated.  I know that I could simply pass the StoreId as the second parameter to the stored procedure, but I was wondering if it's smart/possible to do it this way, passing the `StoreName` as the second parameter.  Pretend this isn't a contrived scenario and `CustomerId` has to be passed as a parameter as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this accomplishes what you're trying to do, except that I've removed the join and just declared a new variable inside the procedure, which grabs the ID of the store based on the name that the user inputs.  It then updates the table with the ID of the store, even though the user didn't input the store ID (because the user wouldn't know this, but the system would).

Granted, depending on what you're trying to do, this still may not work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spUpdateCustomerInformation
 @CustomerID int
,@StoreName varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @ID INT
SELECT @ID = StoreId FROM Stores WHERE StoreName = @StoreName


UPDATE Customers
SET StoreId = @ID
WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerID

END
```

Updated because initially, I copied and pasted from my database to test it, then copied it back trying to use the other names (bad idea).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are joining `Customers` with `Stores` ON storeID, `c.storeID` will always equal `s.storeID`,

In order to accomplish what you're attempting, there must be a third inner join, to figure out the storeId of the `@StoreName` you are passing in.

Comment: this hadn't crossed my min.